# What does "See it styled" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

I browsed a watch website and there's a section for an image gallery and the title "See it styled". The images in the gallery depict the watch worn by different people in different situations. The appearance of the watch is the same in all the pictures. I interpret the title to mean "See it worn".

What does "See it styled" mean in this context, and is it the correct use of the word "styled"?

[image]
https://www.mvmtwatches.com/collections/all-mens-watches/products/chrono-gun-metal-sandstone-leather

Comment: I think it might refer to the images below that heading where the watch has different faces and bands.  The watch can be "styled" by making selections from a range of options. For example, you could use **style** as a verb: *Style your watch by choosing from the following bands and faces* and **styled** would be an adjective formed from the past participle of that transitive verb.

Answer (score 1):

**styled** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/styled)

> the way in which something is said, done, expressed, or performed

As in:

*See X worn, used or in action.*

Comment: Given that X is the watch, do I interpret that as "See the watch *expressed*"? It doesn't sound right to me

Comment: See the watch performing!

Comment: @forsvunnet It sounds like some pretentious advertising copywriter's idea of a word that makes the watch sound cool and desirable. It doesn't, it's just confusing. Don't worry about it, it's advertising and should be ignored as much as possible.

Comment: @forsvunnet The better-matching verb is "done," and what is being done is the wearing of the watch in a certain setting or environment, which matches your original interpretation of "see it worn."

Comment: For many people, watches are fashion objects rather than (purely) functional time-measuring devices, so it is the watch being worn in different styles. In the same way that a clothing catalog might "style" a scarf with a jumper, under a coat, tied in different ways, etc.

Comment: The dictionary definition is for the *noun* **style**, not the adjective or verb. Try looking at **tr.v**

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster gives as one of the [definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/style) of the verb **style** the following:

> to wear (something, such as an article of clothing) as part of a particular fashion look

It's obvious that the website is showing examples of the watch worn as part of a particular fashion look. As Merriam-Webster online is frequently updated, I assume this definition was added since the question was first posted.

Answer (score -1):

> What does "See it styled" mean in this context, and is it the correct
> use of the word "styled"?

It is typical advertising shorthand. It just means "Look at the watch being worn stylishly by the people in the following pictures."

Part of the purpose of such language is to give the reader pause and make them think about the meaning of the words and the product. That way they are more likely to remember it and eventually buy it. It's common these days to make a slogan into a mini-puzzle in order to engage the reader's mind.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found all of the above answers correct and would like to elaborate on the psychological aspect of the advert. The advertisement wants you to see how the watch looks when worn with different combinations of outfits and in varied situations/backgrounds. Maybe, they want to convey that the watch would go well in formal as well as informal situations.

Also, I agree with @chasly-supports Monica who pointed it out as being an advertisement gig (I saw a *"see the fit"* in the link given by you).